# Ngnix server giving 502 error when using supervisor

Tags: php, docker, nginx, supervisord

There is problem with Docker when using supervisor . Actually server doesn't give any error . When starting supervisor emerges problems which when enter site giving 502 errors !

When uncomment follow code in image php giving error

**#ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]**

Follow docker.yml

```
  services:
      webapp:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Docker/php/prod.Dockerfile
        image: webapp:php
        container_name: webapp
        restart: always
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
          - ./Docker/php/ini/volume_conf.prod.conf:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/volume_conf.prod.conf
          - ./Docker/php/supervisor/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
          - ./Docker/php/supervisor/multiProductRunner.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/multiProductRunner.conf
          - ./Docker/php/supervisor/crawlingProductsRunner.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/crawlingProductsRunner.conf
          #- ./Docker/php/supervisor/start-container:/usr/local/bin/start-container
          - ./source/:/var/www/html
        networks:
          customnetwork:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10
      db:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Docker/mysql/Dockerfile
          image: mariadb
          container_name: db
          restart: always
          ports:
            - "3306:3306"
          environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ''
            MYSQL_USER: 'user'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
          volumes:
            - ./Docker/mysql/volume/:/var/lib/mysql
          networks:
            customnetwork:
              ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11
          healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p password" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
      nginx:
          image: nginx:alpine
          container_name: nginx
          tty: true
          volumes:
            - ./source/:/var/www/html
            - ./Docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
          ports:
            - "9001:80"
          networks:
            customnetwork:
              ipv4_address: 172.20.0.12
      meilisearch:
          image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
          ports:
          - '7700:7700'
          volumes:
          - './Docker/meilisearch/volume/:/meili_data'
          networks:
            customnetwork:
              ipv4_address: 172.20.0.13
          healthcheck:
              test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "5"]
              retries: 3
              timeout: 5s
  networks:
    customnetwork:
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

PHP version 8.1 image file (problem is there

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# PHP extensions

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip


RUN echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini


RUN apt-get remove  supervisor --yes
RUN apt-get install  supervisor --yes
RUN service supervisor start

#COPY ./Docker/php/supervisor/multiProductRunner.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
#COPY ./Docker/php/supervisor/start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container

#RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

# when uncomment follow code giving error
#ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]

#EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: So your supervisor config is wrong and nginx is not starting. Show content of `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`. Also analyse supervisor logs

Comment: This is content supervisor . Where is problem. I checking with logs (tail -f) online type. Supervisor working corretcly, when it working then server giving 502

Comment: [program:webStart]
command=php /var/www/html/vendor/webapp/softmaker webStart
startsecs = 0
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startretries = 4
stdout_logfile=/var/log/work.supervisor.out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/work.supervisor.err.log